# How to select by date on timestamp column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table with entries having `timestamp`.

Now I want to select entries just based on a date (day-specific), neglegting the time.

Is that possible, or would I have to save `sql.date` column additionally to fetch all entries of a specific date?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntry {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
}
```

This sql will get no result, because the query is looking only for dates with no time portion.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable wher date = '2015-10-10'
```

Comment: @downvoter: please give a reason

Comment: `select * from myentry where date::date = date '2015-10-10'`. Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only is it a reserved word, but it also does not document the meaning of the column. Is it a "due date", a "start date", a "release date", ....?

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right, in my application the field is of course not named just `date`.!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast this to a timestamp or timstamp with timezone

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE date >= '2015-10-10 00:00:00.000'::timestamp
   AND date < '2015-10-11 00:00:00.000'::timestamp
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-10-10 00:00:00.000'::timestamp AND '2015-10-11 00:00:00.000'::timestamp
```

if the query is autogenerated you should think about changing the generation base from date to long.

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: sorry. I've overlooked that. I change my post